# WP 8.1 ViewModel Processing Property

Tags: c#, viewmodel, win-universal-app

I am writing a WP 8.1 App using ViewModels.  Almost all these viewmodels have a processing property which gets updated if something is happening for example loading/updating data.  I bind this to a processing ring.  My problem is that this variable is set and references everywhere in the viewmodel which makes it messy.  Is there a more elegant way to do this?  Given below is a sample

```C#
public class CustomViewModel
{
   public bool Processing{get;set;}

   Public Void Load()
   {
      Processing = true;
      //Logic to load the data
      Processing = false;
   }

   Public Void Save()
   {
      Processing = true;
      //Logic to save the data
      Processing = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Try inheriting your VM from an abstract base VM, put the processing logic in  there. This only solves making things in your main VM less messy.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the only option I have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all processing methods have no return value, one possible way is by creating a method that accept [`Action Delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) parameter. This method is responsible for setting `Processing` property and invoking the `Action` passed as the method parameter :

```
public bool Processing { get; set; }

private void Process(Action process)
{
    Processing = true;
    process();
    Processing = false;
}

public void Load()
{
    //Logic to load the data
}

public void Save()
{
    //Logic to save the data
}
```

Example usage :

```
//pass 'Load' method as parameter to load data :
Process(Load);
//pass 'Save' method as parameter to save data :
Process(Save);
```

Though, I haven't verified my self whether `Action` delegate is supported in WP 8.1 universal apps, so it will be great to hear from you.

Comment: I dont think this will work since the process methods each have their own unique signatures.